# How to enable "Run function" or "Replay function" in Azure Webjob 3.0?

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs, function-invocation

I have some continuous webjobs 3.0 with QueueTrigger on Azure. I would like to enable the "Run function" and "Replay Function" in Azure Dashboard.

[image]

How can I do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue for webjobs 3.x onwards. Check this [issue comment](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/issues/1716#issuecomment-485967715) and this [comment](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/issues/2179#issuecomment-485555607).

So from WebJobs SDK 3.x onwards, `AddDashboardLogging()` is obsolete actually it should be removed however looks like thy forget to remove it.

If you insist on this feature, suppose you have to use the webjob 2.x version and I test v2 could implement this feature.